# Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1 Crashes when Remote Debugging deploy website

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, crash

Environment:

**Remote Server:**

- Windows Server 2012 Standard x64
- Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger, Version 14.0.24720.0, built by D14REL

[image: Remote Server]

Local Workstation:

- Windows 7 x64
- Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1, Version 14.0.24720.00

[image: Local Workstation]

**Try to Connect**: Launch Remote Debugger on the Server, and Connect to remote debugger in Visual Studio:

[image: Launch Remote Debugger]

Once it Connected, Visual Studio Crashed:

[image: Visual Studio Crashed]

[image: Visual Studio Crashed]

Event Viewer info:

[image: Event Viewer info]

PS.: VS 2013 works OK with the Corresponding Remote Debugger, the same Server and Workstation Environment.

Any suggestion?

dean 
2016.03.12